# Intent not working (Showing errors)

Tags: android, android-intent

while starting intent on image button click "Intent intent = new Intent(this,Settings.class);" showing error in eclipse. Any thing wrong on my code? Here's my code.. Help appreciated..

```
imageButton =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(this,Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: What errors are you having? Show your logcat? Have you registered your `settings` activity in your manifest file?

Comment: use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` in first parameter of Intent's constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this

```
imageButton =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentCLass.this,Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

and check your manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sampledatabase"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

if you only see `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

and no `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`

create a new activity like this

```
<activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="name.of.your.package.Settings" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

remember to put it inside your `<application` tag same as your .MainActivity

Comment: you're welcome! If your question has been answered please tick the check icon to set this as correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Settings.class);
       startActivity(intent);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do two things
First
start your activity like this

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext, Setting.class);
startActivity(intent);

Second thing Mention this class into Android manifest.xml
inside application tag
below the by default activitytag

I think this way you can  resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try below code.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(yourclassName.this,Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Settings.class);
```

use this line of code

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(yourclassName.this,Settings.class);

    Because you using anonymus class for OnClickListener.
    So you can provide the reference with class name. this
```

Answer (score -1):

Add your Settings activity in AndroidManifest.xml